# Get-WmiObject command line ADDING text to variable

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

This is the functioning code:

```
$Result1 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor |
```

I would like to "ADD TEXT AS LABEL" like this:

```
$Result1 = "ADD TEXT AS LABEL" & Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor |
```

Any and all suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Label how? As in a table with a label above? Or add text front of the result of the WMIObject?

Comment: `"ADD TEXT AS LABEL" + (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor)`

Comment: Even text in front would be confusing; in front of which property? There's an empty pipeline at the end, what happens after that? And because it's there, the concatenation operator is `+`, `&` is the call operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subexpression:

```
$Result1 = $("ADD TEXT AS LABEL"; Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor) | ...
```